# Is the AISC's Steel Construction Manual's out of plane "special case" valid for all weld groups?

Tags: structures, welds, aisc

In the AISC's *Steel Construction Manual* Table 8-4 "Coefficients C for Eccentrically Loaded Weld Groups", it mentions the Special Case where the load is not in plane with the weld group.  [image: Special Case]

However, this Special Case is not mentioned again for the remainder of the weld groups in the rest of the chapter's tables on other weld groups.  For example:
[image: No Special Case]

Why wouldn't the out of plane case be applicable to the other weld groups?.  I hesitate to apply the case to other groups when the manual doesn't explicitly state it's valid.  The manual as a whole is rather explicit, so I believe that if the special case is not mentioned for the other groups, it's not valid to use it for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AISC consultant engineer responded to this in an email.  The answer is no, the special case only applies to Table 8-4 geometry.  My interpretation of the reasoning is as follows.

These tables are for loads in the same plane as the weld group.  The geometry of two closely spaced parallel welds is approximately in plane with the load regardless of the orientation.  This is something of an exception (hence the "special case") of the geometry and I believe that if the perpendicular distance between the welds in the tables increased much more than shown (i.e. k > 2) then this special case would also be invalid for this weld group geometry.